# ImageView with rounded corners, border AND shadow behind everything?

Tags: android

I've managed to achieve a rounded `ImageView` with a shadows behind it but i didn't achieve the border. is there a way for it?

[my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00yXZ.jpg). [wanted result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zdh9m.jpg).

- edit: my app needs to support api 19.

code for `imageView`:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/image_view_container"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/coupon_item_index_text_view"
    android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame"
    android:rotation="-7"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_width="90dp">

    <ImageView
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:id="@+id/coupon_item_image_view"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_border_corners"
        android:src="@drawable/pizza"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

and the code for `@drawable/rounded_border_corners`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="8dp" />
    <stroke android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@color/white" />
    <solid android:color="#00000000" />
</shape>
```

using `CardView` as @nilesh-rathod suggested with a few adjustments results in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIbmx.jpg). still seems like the shadow is missing. code:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    card_view:cardElevation="2dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
    card_view:contentPadding="2dp"
    android:id="@+id/image_view_container"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/coupon_item_index_text_view"
    android:rotation="-7"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_width="86dp">

    <ImageView
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:id="@+id/coupon_item_image_view"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_border_corners"
        android:src="@drawable/pizza"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Have you tried `<solid android:color="@color/white" />` in your drawable ?

Comment: yes i did. i got the same result.

Answer (score 0):

try this use `android.support.v7.widget.CardView` insted of `FrameLayout`

compile cardview `dependencies`

```
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0'
```

than use like below code

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/image_view_container"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:rotation="-7">

    <ImageView
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:id="@+id/coupon_item_image_view"
        android:src="@drawable/bg"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

try this also use **CircleImageView**

```
dependencies {

compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
 }
```

use this way

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/profile_image"
    android:layout_width="96dp"
    android:layout_height="96dp"
    android:src="@drawable/profile"
    app:civ_border_width="2dp"
    app:civ_border_color="#FF000000"/>
```

Comment: thanks a lot, but my app needs to support api >= 19 and `CardView` was introduced in api 24.

Comment: cardview also support api >=19

Comment: im not sure im getting shadow and border now. i've updated my post with new code.

Comment: @user1974368 than use **CircleImageView**